# Handle fetch in service worker but allow client to see redirect

Tags: service-worker

I have a url, `/users/sign_out`, that is supposed log out a user and redirect them to my root url, `/`. I want to handle this fetch through my service worker, because I want to clean some items out of the cache before sending the user back to root. However, since the client doesn't see the redirect that happens on the fetch from the service worker, the user winds up on my splash screen but sees the pre-redirect address `/users/sign_out`.

Is there any way currently that I can handle the fetch and also allow the client to see the correct final url?

It appears that eventually there will be a `Response.redirect()` method that will allow updating a response with the final url. It looks like there is also likely to be some kind of `finalURL` option that would also address this case. But is there anything that I can use now? On Twitter, Jake Archibald (@jaffathecake) said I could construct a new Response myself - and I can, but even after looking at the spec and the MDN docs a bit, I still can't figure out how to specify the correct url for it.

If there is in fact a way to construct a Response object that does what I need, could someone show me how that works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an example at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/service-worker/mock-responses showing how you could create a `Response` object and use it to respond to a `fetch` event.

In that case, we're creating a `200 OK` response with a body, but there's nothing stopping you from creating an arbitrary response. You'd probably want a [`302 Found`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) for your use case, so you'd do something like:

```
var responseInit = {
  status: 302,
  statusText: 'Found',
  headers: {
    Location: '/' // Or whatever URL you want to redirect to.
  }
};

var redirectResponse = new Response('', responseInit);
event.respondWith(redirectResponse);
```

You can include code that clears your caches inside the `fetch` handler before you respond to the event, and you'd obviously want to check the `event.request.url` value first to make sure you only respond to requests for `/users/sign_out` with your custom response.

Comment: So this would tell the client to make a new fetch for `/`, right, so I would wind up fetching it twice? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: That should just result for a single HTTP request for `/`, originating from your browser automatically in response to the HTTP 302.

Comment: I mean will I fetch `/` once from the service worker and then again from the browser in response to the redirect from the service worker?

Comment: Either way, I can work with this, so I'll accept the answer. Thanks for the example.

Comment: There will be one request for / triggered by the browser when it handles the HTTP 302. Whether or not your SW's fetch handler is triggered by that request depends on whether the SW scope includes /. There are not going to be two real HTTP requests made for /.